# How can I get the response of an AppleScript dialog box in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess, applescript

I'm trying to use python to create a dialog box prompt with buttons using AppleScript for my Mac.

With the regular dialog box with 'OK' and 'Cancel' I have been simply doing `r = os.system("osascript -e 'Tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \""+body+"\"'")` because `r == 0` if 'OK' is pressed, and `r == 256` if 'Cancel' is pressed.

But now I want buttons. I tried `r = os.system("osascript -e 'Tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \"Would you like do download audio or video?\" buttons {\"Audio\", \"Video\"}'")` but both buttons return `r == 0` if clicked.

I've tried using `subprocess.Popen()` based on some examples online, but I'm getting errors because I don't really understand it. I can't find an example online that uses AppleScript like I'm using.

Can anyone please point me in the right dirrection for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Empirical* answer follows...

Try running your `osascript` command directly in the Terminal, rather than via **Python** and its `subprocess` module. Then you can examine both the exit status, and the output on `stdout` and `stderr` so you know where to look in **Python**.

---

So, first let's look at exit status, just using the Terminal:

```
osascript -e "SOMETHING"
echo $?
```

The value printed will match the exit staus from **Python** `subprocess`, so try clicking different buttons and see what you get.

---

Next, look at `stdout` and `stderr`. So, run your `osascript` command again but redirect the `stdout` to a file called `stdout.txt` and the `stderr` to a file called `stderr.txt`:

```
osascript -e "SOMETHING" > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

Run a few times selecting different options and pressing different buttons in your dialog, but check the contents of `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt` after each using:

```
cat stdout.txt
cat stderr.txt
```

When you know whether the output you want is in the exit status, or on `stdout` or `stderr` you will know what to look for in **Python**.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I was still confused how to actually use subprocess in python, but I managed to learn based on what you explained.
I solved it like this: 
`r = subprocess.Popen("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to return button returned of (display dialog \"Would you like do download audio or video?\" buttons {\"Audio\", \"Video\"})'", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
`stdout = r.stdout.read().decode().strip()`

Comment: @AlfieStoppani Cool - glad you *"got"* what I was trying to explain and built on that to get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Shell commands send their results to standard output or standard error.  AppleScript’s `display dialog` returns a *record* ( `{button returned: "OK"}` for example), with the shell returning the textual representation.  You can wrangle the returned text to get the button title, or just have AppleScript return the desired record key, for example:

```
import os
r = os.system("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to return button returned of (display dialog \"Would you like do download audio or video?\" buttons {\"Audio\", \"Video\"})'")
```

Note that using `os.system` is not recommended these days.
I don't have a current Python install, but to use subprocess it would be something like:

```
import subprocess
script = 'tell application "System Events" to return button returned of (display dialog "Would you like to download audio or video?" buttons {"Audio", "Video"})'
result = subprocess.check_output(['osascript', '-e', script], text = True)
print(result)
```

Comment: It prints 'Audio' or 'Video' to the console yes, but in both cases `r == 0` so how would I use logic to do something based on which was pressed?
How can I save the 'audio' or 'video' response as a variable? `os.popen()` isn't working either I just get a null string or something like that.

Comment: @AlfieStoppani - I don't have Python installed but added another subprocess example.